# Bungie Api. Help is becoming JsonNull?

Tags: java, api

I'm currently working on a final project for a lower level comp-sci class and we are working with the Bungie API and we are trying to get the bnetMembershipId. However, when we try to access the data we keep getting null errors. We don't know how else to get this data and don't know why it is returning as null.

The link I am getting from is:

http://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/2/Profile/4611686018429022888/LinkedProfiles/

We want the `bnetMembershipId` it returns.
Here is the code we are using to pull the data:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonNull;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive;

public class GetBungieAccount  {
    private static String apiKey = "";

   public static String getBungieAccount(String membershipId, String membershipType) throws Exception{
        String url = "http://www.bungie.net/Platform/Destiny2/"+ membershipType+ "/Profile/" +membershipId+ "/LinkedProfiles/";
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // Set header
        con.setRequestProperty("X-API-KEY", apiKey);

        //int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        // System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to Bungie.Net : " + url);
        //System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        String response = "";

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response += inputLine;
        }

        in.close();

        /* GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder(); 
        builder.setPrettyPrinting(); 
        Gson gson = builder.create();

        JsonObject ResponseObj = gson.fromJson(response, JsonObject.class);

        JsonElement finalObj =  new JsonObject();
        for(JsonElement value : ResponseObj.getAsJsonArray("Response")){

            finalObj = value;                
        }
        System.out.println(finalObj.toString()); //TEST TO ENSURE THAT FINAL OBJECT GRABS DATA
        JsonObject finalfinalobject = gson.fromJson(finalObj.toString(), JsonObject.class);
        */

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        JsonObject json = (JsonObject) parser.parse(response);

        return json.getAsJsonObject("Response").get("membershipId").toString();


    }
}
```

sorry if this is made poorly first time on StackOverflow

Answer (score 0):

The membershipId is a property of bnetMembership so you could do something like

```
return json.getAsJsonObject("Response").getAsJsonObject("bnetMembership").get(membershipId").toString();
```

There is also an array of profiles in the response which each have a membershipId property as well, but I think you asked in regards to the bnetMembership.

Comment: Yes this is what we have tried  and we were confused as to why it didnt work this is the error we are getting if this helps at all @Justyn2



`
                                                                                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.JsonNull cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject

Comment: Thanks! i didn't think of taking that out